# How to test dockerised Symfony API

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I created a symfony api then dockerised it, and i want to test if my dockerfile is good so i built the docker file then ran it but i couldn t find the right way to acces to my container
this is my dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.4.3-apache

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls &&  mv /var/www/html/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && pecl install mongodb-1.11.0

RUN cd /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && \
echo " extension=mongodb.so " >> docker-php-ext-sodium.ini

COPY ./apache.conf /etc/apache/site-available/000-default.conf
COPY . /var/www

RUN cd /var/www && composer install

WORKDIR /var/www

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "php", "bin/console", "server:run" ]
```

I built the container with : `docker build .`

then ran with `docker run -d -p 8000:8001 [ID]`

Docker ps prints this :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                               NAMES
7f4090f55cd8   4c0648dd5706   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8080/tcp, :::8000->8080/tcp   optimistic_pasteur
```

How can i test  if it's working ?

Comment: Try visiting `localhost:8000`

Comment: @Justinas i tried that an it gives 'ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED'